# boost spsc_queue - how to "try pop"?

Tags: c++, boost, lock-free

I have such queue:

```
    boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<orders_log,  boost::lockfree::capacity<8192>> futOrdersUpdates;
```

My problem is that sometimes I deque same item several times. I've added some troubleshoot code:

```
while (bool dequeued = futOrdersUpdates.pop(entryItem) || !endOfTransaction)
{
    if (!dequeued) {
        dequeueLoger.Debug("no items, try again");
        continue;
    } else {
        if (lastRev != 0 && entryItem.replRev == lastRev) {
            dequeueLoger.Debug("duplicate item!");
        }
        lastRev = entryItem.replRev;
    }
            // further processing
```

The idea is - if `endOfTransaction` flag is not set, I should "spin", otherwise I can exit if queue is empty.

In logs I found strange things:

- "no items, try again" - is NEVER appear
- "duplicate item!" - IS appear.

Expected behavior:

- "no items, try again" should appear sometimes - when queue is empty but `endOfTransaction` flag is not set
- "duplicate item!" should NEVER appear

The question is - if i'm "dequee" spsc_queue correctly? Any bugs in my code?

Comment: You are clearly in the case of multiple consumers, so it's a very bad idea to use a spsc queue when several consumers pop the queue concurrently. Since boost::lockfree does not have (now) a container for single producer/multiple consumer, I suggest you to use the class boost::lockfree::queue, which is multiple producer/multiple consumer.

Comment: no i have one producer one consumer

Comment: Oops, totally misread. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't possibly know why you are getting duplicates, because we have no idea how you fill `replRev`. It could be a data race right there (I hope you don't do `lastRev+1`, e.g.).

1. Note that you likely never get "No items try again" because the loop is skipped entirely, e.g.:

   ```
   while (bool dequeued = foo())
   {  
        assert(dequeued); // can never be false here!
   }
   ```

   will never even enter the loop.
2. The reason you get duplicates is because you say

   ```
   bool dequeued = futOrdersUpdates.pop(entryItem) || !endOfTransaction;
   ```

   As you know (see your comment) this **forces** `dequeued` to be `true` even if no item *was* dequeued, because `endOfTransaction` has not been set yet.

   The value of `entryItem` is *unspecified* at that time - but likely just contains the previous value, leading to the "duplicate" message.

For a nice demo using `spsc_queue` I recently gave, see this answer: [Dynamic generation & safe usage of spsc_queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183629/dynamic-generation-safe-usage-of-spsc-queues/23186918#23186918)

Comment: I have `|| !endOfTransaction` so `dequeued` may be `false`. The question is - if i'm working with `spsc_queue` correctly.

Comment: @javapowered I hope my elaborated answer helps explain. The rest of the answer to "am I working with spsc_queue correctly" cannot be given for the reasons stated in the first paragraph.

Comment: hmmm it seems i should just write `((bool dequeued = futOrdersUpdates.pop(entryItem)) || !endOfTransaction)`

Comment: @javapowered if that would compile... See that linked answer to see how I handled a shutdown flag.